# Why is a segmentation fault occuring in my code after the first time i insert an item in my code

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, malloc, singly-linked-list

```
 /*Linked list insertin deletion display
```

I have declared a global variable of struct node *head=NULL;

linkedlistlinkedlistlinkedlisr=tlinkedlistlinkedlistlinkedlist

linkedlistlinkedlistlinkedlisr=tlinkedlistlinkedlistlinkedlist

```
void insert(int x)//i guess the problem might be that temp is pointing to head as well as new  
{
    struct node *temp=NULL;
    struct node *new;

    new=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->data=x;
    new->next=NULL;

    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=new;
        temp=head;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next=new;
        temp=new;
    }
}
```

Comment: If `head` is not `NULL`, the `else` part of the code does `temp->next=new;` but `temp` was initialized to `NULL` at the top of the function, so this is a _null pointer dereference_.

Comment: Are you trying to insert the new node at the tail end of the list?

Comment: Please indent your code correctly and don't put a blank line between each and every line.

Comment: After entering the if part the temp pointer should point to the first new node created.so when it goes to else part when a second new node is created so I am trying to point the temp to this new node created by temp=new;

Comment: The function will initialize the `temp` variable to `NULL` every time the function is called. It does not remember the value of `temp` from a previous call. The value of `head` is remembered though, because that variable is external to the function.

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing the doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for the case of `head==NULL` is OK. But in the `else` case you need to insert the node correctly.

The code below will insert the node at the end of the list.

```
void insert(int x)
{
    struct node *temp=NULL;
    struct node *newnode;
    newnode= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->data=x;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = head;
        while (temp->next != NULL)
            temp = temp->next;
        temp->next=newnode;
    }
}
```

If you want to insert at the beginning of the list, then you need to modify the `else` condition as shown.

```
else
{
    newnode->next=head;
    head = newnode;
}
```

Also, the following pointers

1. Avoid use of `new` as it is a keyword in C++
2. Do not cast the result of `malloc`

Comment: can you explain how my code is wrong in the else part itself

Comment: So in if part if I have changed head=new; the value of head is still NULL

Answer (score 1):

`temp->next=new` is most likely your problem. At the top of the function you set temp to NULL and by using the `->` operator, you will be dereferencing a null pointer.